# How to scroll to bottom right after instancing a YUI 3 scrollview?

Tags: javascript, yui, yui3

I have instantiated a YUI and I need to scroll to the bottom right away (and also after adding some elements dinamically later). Any ideas how can I do that?

Here is the code so far:

```
yInstance = YUI();

yInstance.use('scrollview-base', function(Y) {
    Y.scrollview = new Y.ScrollView({
        id:"scrollview",
        srcNode: '#scrollview-content',
        height: main_scrollable_div_height,
        flick: {

            minDistance: 10,
            minVelocity: 0.3,
            axis: "y"
        },
        axis: "y"
    });

    Y.scrollview.render();

});
```

I can see in the official docs that there is a "scrollY" variable, but have no idea how to modify it (is it just read-only?)

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

The solution is to add this when initializing "scrollY: max_height":

```
Y.scrollview = new Y.ScrollView({
        id:"scrollview",
        srcNode: '#scrollview-content',
        height: main_scrollable_div_height,
        flick: {

            minDistance: 10,
            minVelocity: 0.3,
            axis: "y"
        },
        axis: "y",
        scrollY: max_height
    });
```